# Extract scalar fields only from an interface in typescript

Tags: typescript, interface

I have the following **interface** available.

```js
interface User {
  id: string
  name: string
  age: number
  gender: Gender
  hobbies: Hobby[]
  addresses: Address[]
}
```

Now I want a new type with all the **scalar** fields as:

```js
interface UserScalars {
  id: string
  name: string
  age: number
  gender: Gender
}
```

I know that I can use `Omit/Exclude` here but there are a lot of **scalar** as well as **no-scalars** in my case so `Omit/Exclude` will only make my code uglier.

is this possible in typescript?

Comment: After creating a type for scalars like `type Scalar = string | number | Gender;`, `Extract` is what you want for `type UserScalars = Extract<User, Scalar>;` and `Omit` is what you want for `type UserNonScalars = Omit<User, Scalar>;`. How do you expect to let TypeScript know what is a scalar and nonscalar without at least defining one (I recommend defining Scalar, since its members are more distinct than NonScalar).

Comment: this is what I did but the final type i.e```UserScalars``` is ```never``` type for some reason.
```typescript
type Scalars = string | number 
\n
type UserScalars = Extract<CampaignDbObject, Scalars>
\n
let x: UserScalars

```

Comment: Ah, sorry, what you want is not `Extract` (this extracts types from a _union_) or `Omit` (this omits _keys_ from a type's properties). You will want to do something like the `PickByValueType` answered below.

Comment: Anyways thanks a lot sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep. It is possible:

```
interface User {
  id: string
  name: string
  age: number
  gender: Gender
  hobbies: Hobby[]
  addresses: Address[]
}

type PickByValueType<T, U> = {
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends U ? K : never]: T[K]
}

type UserScalars = PickByValueType<User, string | number>;
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBA4qAmwBOUDeBYAUFHUCyAggDICiANFAGImGlYC%20WAliAC7IBmAhgMbBQAJAPYAjEQE80jTC3ZJufKAXjwkwAM7qpWZm069%20AVXXI0WHE3gAuKOtZIWAc3NQQXCMBt2HIZ9ihcjp6ukCLILkEgiEg2cFHh-gAWoiJMGjbCYuIA2gC6LlwqaprpSkUa6nkMOpis4gAO-AAKTDwA1gBC4gBqXAA2YMAAKg3AADxDFIYAfFAAvGb%202QDSUCxQbcDiQhxQQwFaQyu5UMAAHuxRWoZQAPxQqzYgwABuyLk2R8v5mNJYdY0oMZkABlHj9LhILQLFrtLq9AbDUZjYFICjeJxQAA%20IQgYSQ0wA3EA)

Comment: Wow it seems to work, but can you also let me know how can I define all the scalars in one place and use it in place of ```string | number```, I am very new to typescript.

Comment: @SuhailibnNisar define the scalars as a type, e.g. `type Scalar = string | number;`

Comment: Ah yeah got it thanks a lot sir, I am newly signed up for stack overflow, so I am sorry I can't upvote your answer.

Comment: Of course. Here you are
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBA4qAmwBOUDeBYAUFHUCyAggDICiANFAGImGlYC+WAliAC7IBmAhgMbBQAJAPYAjEQE80jTC3ZJufKAXjwkwAM7qpWZm069+AVXXI0WHE3gAuKOtZIWAc3NQQXCMBt2HIZ9ihcjp6ukCLILkEgiEg2cFHh-gAWoiJMGjbCYuIA2gC6LlwqaprpSkUa6nkMOpis4gAO-AAKTDwA1gBC4gBqXAA2YMAAKg3AADxDFIYAfFAAvGb+2QDSUCxQbcDiQhxQQwFaQyu5UMAAHuxRWoZQAPxQqzYgwABuyLk2R8v5mNJYdY0oABlHj9LgoBbgCBhFAAH1s9icUHhIiEQj6wC4IGRUAASsBHCQzvUcalHLIceA+n0cWB4hwWMB4DUAUYTEgQWCkFoFi12l1egNhqMxsZkBROX1wdMANxAA

Comment: One more thing can you share some resources where can I learn these advanced typescript stuff I don't even know what keyword to use to google them. I am talking about this:  ```type PickByValueType<T, U> = {
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends U ? K : never]: T[K]
}```